# Javascript, sorting a numerical array above greater than zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numeric

Please can anyone help me.  I am able to sort an array into either ascending or descending order but I want to be able to sort the array above a numeric value.

For example if I have an array:

```
a0 = new Array(8, 1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0);
// Sort a0 to end up with;
// 1, 3, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0;
```

I have included a fiddle:
[Basic template](https://jsfiddle.net/a4poster/t8j4v5hu/2/)

I can only get it to work but with the zeros at the front of the sorted array

```
// 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 9;
```

Thanks.

Comment: [*sort*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#examples) can take a compare function to evaluate the values to sort to ensure the correct the sort order: `[8, 1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0].sort((a, b) => a > 0?  a - b :  +Infinity )`.

Comment: Could you edit the question to add clarity around what "sort the array above a numeric value" means?

Comment: @RobG your function doesn't give the correct result.

Comment: @jefi—it returns `[1, 3, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, which is what the OP asked for. If there are other requirements, the OP needs to state them. Anyway, it's just an example of a sort function that fits the OP.

Comment: Sorry but I get `[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 9 ]` as result of `console.log([8, 1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0].sort((a, b) => a > 0?  a - b :  +Infinity ))`

Comment: @jefi—seems to depend on the implementation: Safari and Chrome give required result, Firefox not.  Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort zeros with a check of being not zero and move this values to bottom.

```js
const array = [8, 1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0];

array.sort((a, b) => !a - !b || a - b);

console.log(...array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write a custom comparator function for the `Array.prototype.sort` function that ensures that `0` will be sorted last:

```js
const a0 = new Array(8, 1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0);

a0.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === 0) return 1;
  if (b === 0) return -1;
  return a - b;
});

console.log(a0);
```

Comment: All right! Now it is working!

Comment: This effectively just filters out 0 and puts it at the end, values less than 0 are sorted normally. `a === 0` should probably be `a <= 0` etc. ;-)

Comment: @RobG This produces the result OP wanted: unless we get more information on how OP wants to handle negative numbers.

Comment: "*either ascending or descending order … able to sort the array above a numeric value.*" It misses on both those criteria. But it's on the right track. :-)